# Determine how many terms of the original series should be S should be added up

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

[image]

So the clinician I spoke to told me it should be a simple operation like 
$$(0.05)^n/n - 0.25^n < .0001$$

Which gave me some the value .996 which is obviously a non-nonsensical answer for a  question asking how many terms of a series are necessary to essentially be accurate to the true value to 3 decimal places. How do I restart my effort of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \Delta S_k \equiv \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n 4^n}- \sum_{n=1}^k\frac{1}{n 4^n}
=\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n 4^n}
$$
$$
\Delta S_k<\frac 1k\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ 4^n}=\frac 1{k 4^{k+1}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{ 4^n}=\frac{1}{3k4^k}
$$
this will be less than 0.0001 provided that 
$$ (3k)4^k > 10 000  \tag1$$

a good guess is the solution to $3 (4^k)=10000$ which gives $k\approx 5.8$ 
Try integers close to this in equation (1)  
I think you will find that $k=5$ is the smallest $k$ for which you can be confident that $\Delta S_k<0.0001$